# EKEventEditViewController wrong start/end dates saved in iCal

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a strange issue, i am using EKEventEditViewController to save event from my app.
the code is

```
- (void)addEvent:(id)sender {

    // When add button is pushed, create an EKEventEditViewController to display the event.
    EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    // set the addController's event store to the current event store.
    addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
    addController.event.title = self.reportTitle;

    // present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
    [self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

    addController.editViewDelegate = self;
    [addController release];
}
```

Problem is that its working fine in my iOS 5 iphone. But when i tested it in iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.1, it store wrong start/end dates and time in iCal. Can any one guide me whats going wrong.

Comment: I found the reason of above problem, writing here so that it may help someone else. 
"When Time Zone Support is on, Calendar displays event dates and times in the time zone set for your calendars. When Time Zone Support is off, Calendar displays events in the time zone of your current location."